# Select2 with AngularJS not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-select2

I am trying to get `select2` library working with AngularJS select.

I am created a small jsfiddle with the same option values which i am using in my project.

But the select2 seems to be working wrongly.
For Eg: When I select index 2, it shows value from index 3. For the first tome it works fine, but from the second time it breaks.

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/k5215nvn/)

Has anyone faced this issue till now?

Comment: The event handlers added by jQuery fight the event handlers added by the AngularJS directives. Use [tag:angular-ui-select] - AngularJS native version of Select2 and Selectize

Comment: can you please share an example of angularjs-select?

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

Comment: I agree with @georgeawg to use angular plugins libs. But sometimes you just don't get exact same library in angular. So considering that, I've posted the working solution.  You can check if it works or you can always use angular-ui set of libraries like ui-bootstrap, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using way too older version of `angularjs`. At least use 1.4.x There are many breaking changes after 1.2. So, at least from 1.4 it's quite stable. I've created following plunker example from your jsfiddle code. It's working as expected.

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/B6VLwLliAHrP775C6Tbr?p=preview)**

Comment: This works. But I dont understand why @georgeawg  wrote "event handlers added by jQuery fight the event handlers added by the AngularJS directives".
It shouldn't have worked for 1.4 either.

Comment: @NagendraSingh What he said is correct. but angularjs doesn't have problem with jquery. They recommended not to use but if you add the lib before angularjs in index.html then angularjs itself starts using the external jquery. But very old version of angularjs has problem with recent versions of jquery.